# Looping SQL until dependent cell is empty

Tags: sql, vba, while-loop, cell

So far I have this code; i'm trying to loop my sql search as long as the cell I6, the first cell with data (as well as subsequent cells)  is not empty.  I can't figure out how to make the 'cusip' depend on the same cell i am looping [3rd line ...where s.cusip = & Sheet1.Range("I6") ].

i.e. when cell I7 is not empty use I7 in the query.

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cell(I, 6 + C))
    'SQL function'
    oRS.Source = "select s.cusip, s.description, s.rate as coupon, sa.rrb_factor from  security s left join security_analytics sa on s.security_id = sa.security_id where s.cusip = & Sheet1.Range("I6") and sa.as_of_date = trunc(sysdate);"
    oRS.Open  
'copying data into excel'
.cell(W,6+C).CopyFromRecordset oRS

C = C + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Why don't you just try to use MS Query?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like:

```
Const COL_CUSIP as long = 9 'I
Const COL_RS as long = 23 'W
C=6     

With Sheet1

Do While Len(.Cells(C, COL_CUSIP).Value)>0
    'SQL function'
    oRS.Source = "select s.cusip, s.description, s.rate as coupon, " & _ 
          " sa.rrb_factor from  security s " & _
          "left join security_analytics sa on " & _ 
          " s.security_id = sa.security_id where s.cusip = " & _
          .Cells(C, COL_CUSIP).Value & " and sa.as_of_date = trunc(sysdate);"
    oRS.Open  
    'copying data into excel'
    if not oRS.EOF then .Cells(C, COL_RS).CopyFromRecordset oRS
    oRS.Close
    C = C + 1
Loop

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cell(I, 6 + C))
    'SQL function'
    oRS.Source = "select s.cusip, s.description, s.rate as coupon, sa.rrb_factor " + _
                  "from  security s left join security_analytics sa on " + _
                  "s.security_id = sa.security_id where s.cusip = " + _
                  "Sheet1.Range("I6") + " and sa.as_of_date = trunc(sysdate);"
    oRS.Open  
'copying data into excel'
.cell(W,6+C).CopyFromRecordset oRS

C = C + 1
Loop
```